# Postgresql: How to take incremental backup with Barman

Tags: postgresql, database-backups, barman

I am new to Postgresql, I've found a tool named Barman for taking incremental backup of database. But the few tutorials aren't helping that much as they're not for naive users.

Can someone help explaining the steps simply how to backup data with Barman? That would be a great help ! I'm using Postgres 10.4 in Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: are you using postgres as service in aws?

Comment: No, I just have an S3 bucket. Postgresql database is running on my machine. I'm trying to upload the database from my machine to S3 bucket everytime database is updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this great tutorial](http://rajeshmadiwale.blogspot.com/2016/03/barmanbackup-and-recovery-manager-is.html) later explaining step by step process. This one is by far the most helpful one. I am including the content in case link becomes invalid if the page changes.

Barman (backup and recovery manager) is an administration tool for disaster recovery of PostgreSQL servers written in Python. Barman can perform remote backups of multiple servers in business critical environments, and helps DBAs during the recovery phase.
Barman’s most wanted features include: backup catalogues, incremental backup, retention policies, remote recovery, archiving and compression of WAL files and of backups.

Steps To Setup pgbarman:

Step 1 : Install PostgreSQL-9.4 or 9.5.

Download PostgreSQL from below link

https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/source/v9.5.1/postgresql-9.5.1.tar.bz2

Step 2 : Download pgbarman from below link.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pgbarman/files/1.5.1/barman-1.5.1.tar.gz/download

Step3: Install prerequisite before installing pgbarman below are necessary prerequisite.

Python 2.6 or 2.7
Python modules:

- argcomplete
- argh >= 0.21.2
- psycopg2
- python-dateutil < 2.0 (since version 2.0 requires python3)
- distribute (optional)

PostgreSQL >= 8.3
rsync >= 3.0.4

Step4: untar the pgbarman file and install it as given below

```
[root@localhost ~] tar -xvf barman-1.5.1.tar.gz
[root@localhost ~] cd barman-1.5.1
[root@localhost barman-1.5.1] python2.6 setup.py build
[root@localhost barman-1.5.1] python2.6 setup.py install
```

Step5: copy barman.conf from doc to /etc/

```
[root@localhost barman-1.5.1] cp doc/barman.conf /etc/
```

Step6: create user barman and change the owner of /etc/barman.conf

```
[root@localhost barman-1.5.1]# chown -R barman:barman /etc/barman.conf
```

Step7: Make password less authentication between barman server and postgres server .

```
[barman@localhost ~]$ ssh-keygen
[barman@localhost ~]$ ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub postgres@127.0.0.1
```

Repeat above steps for postgres user.

```
[root@localhost barman-1.5.1]# su - postgres
[postgres@localhost ~]$ ssh-keygen
[postgres@localhost ~]$ ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub barman@127.0.0.1
```

Step8: Edit barman.conf and edit below parameters in config file

```
[barman]
barman_home = /home/barman
barman_user = barman
log_file = /home/barman/barman.log
compression = gzip
reuse_backup = link
minimum_redundancy = 1
[main-db-server]
description = "Main DB Server"
ssh_command = ssh postgres@127.0.0.1
conninfo = host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres
```

Step9: Edit the postgresql.conf and enable the archiving .

There is one last configuration to be made on the main, to switch on backup (or archive) mode. First, we need to locate the value of the incoming backup directory from the barman, switch to the user barman:

```
         su - barman
```

Run below command to locate the incoming backup directory:

```
 barman show-server main | grep incoming_wals_directory  
incoming_wals_directory: /home/barman/main/incoming

Note down the value of incoming_wals_directory in my setup it's/home/barman/main/incoming
```

Now switch to the user postgres on postgres server.

- Open the postgresql.conf and make the following changes to the file:
  Uncomment the wal_level parameter and set its value to archive.
  Uncomment the archive_mode parameter and set its value to on.
  Uncomment the archive_command parameter and set its value to 'rsync -a %p barman@127.0.0.1:/home/barman/main/incoming/%f'.
  Use the IP address of the Barman server. If you got a different value for incoming_wals_directory.

Step10: Restart postgres server or instance .

```
pg_ctl -D /home/postgres/master restart
```

Step11: Now loging to the barman (su – barman) and check wether barman can connect to postgres or not .

```
Barman check main
```

Note : here 'main' is name for postgres instance which is declared in barman.conf.

```
[barman@localhost ~]$ barman check main
Server main:
PostgreSQL: OK
archive_mode: OK
wal_level: OK
archive_command: OK
continuous archiving: OK
directories: OK
retention policy settings: OK
backup maximum age: OK (no last_backup_maximum_age provided)
compression settings: OK
minimum redundancy requirements: FAILED (have 0 backups, expected at least 1)
ssh: OK (PostgreSQL server)
not in recovery: OK
```

Step12 : Below command gives the information of the postgres server

```
[barman@localhost ~]$ barman show-server main
Server main:
active: True
archive_command: false
archive_mode: on
archived_count: 0
backup_directory: /home/barman/main
backup_options: BackupOptions(['exclusive_backup'])
bandwidth_limit: None
basebackup_retry_sleep: 30
basebackup_retry_times: 0
basebackups_directory: /home/barman/main/base
compression: None
config_file: /home/postgres/data/postgresql.conf
conninfo: host=127.0.0.1 user=postgres port=5432
copy_method: rsync
current_archived_wals_per_second: 0.0
current_xlog: 000000010000000000000043
custom_compression_filter: None
custom_decompression_filter: None
data_directory: /home/postgres/data
description: Main PostgreSQL Database
disabled: False
failed_count: 0
```

Step13 : Take first full backup of main using barman

```
[barman@localhost ~]$ barman backup main
Starting backup for server main in /home/barman/main/base/20160226T134115
Backup start at xlog location: 0/48000028 (000000010000000000000048, 00000028)
Copying files.
Copy done.
Asking PostgreSQL server to finalize the backup.
Backup size: 480.8 MiB. Actual size on disk: 480.8 MiB (-0.00% deduplication ratio).
Backup end at xlog location: 0/480000C0 (000000010000000000000048, 000000C0)
Backup completed
Processing xlog segments for main
Older than first backup. Trashing file 000000010000000000000047 from server main
000000010000000000000048
000000010000000000000048.00000028.backup
```

Step14 : login to postgres and create database and tables, insert data into tables then take incremental backup of main using barman(login to barman).

Adding data to postgres :

```
    [postgres@localhost ~]$ psql
    psql (9.5.1)
    Type "help" for help.
    postgres=# \dt
    List of relations
    Schema | Name | Type | Owner
    --------+------------------+-------+----------
    public | pgbench_accounts | table | postgres
    public | pgbench_branches | table | postgres
    public | pgbench_history | table | postgres
    public | pgbench_tellers | table | postgres
    public | test | table | postgres
    public | test1 | table | postgres
    public | test2 | table | postgres
    public | test4 | table | postgres
    public | test5 | table | postgres
    public | test6 | table | postgres
    (10 rows)
    postgres=# create database test;
    CREATE DATABASE
    postgres=# \c test
    You are now connected to database "test" as user "postgres".
    test=# create table test1(i int);
    CREATE TABLE
    test=# create table test2(i int);
    CREATE TABLE
    test=# insert into test1 values (generate_series(1,1000));
    INSERT 0 1000
    test=# insert into test2 values (generate_series(1,1000));
    INSERT 0 1000
    test=# \q

Now take incremental backup using barman :
[barman@localhost ~]$ barman backup --reuse=link main
Starting backup for server main in /home/barman/main/base/20160226T134400
Backup start at xlog location: 0/4A000028 (00000001000000000000004A, 00000028)
Copying files.
Copy done.
Asking PostgreSQL server to finalize the backup.
Backup size: 488.0 MiB. Actual size on disk: 7.3 MiB (-98.50% deduplication ratio).
Backup end at xlog location: 0/4A0000C0 (00000001000000000000004A, 000000C0)
Backup completed
Processing xlog segments for main
000000010000000000000049
00000001000000000000004A
00000001000000000000004A.00000028.backup
```

Note : --reuse= link is used to link the main full backup . This will backup only modified or changed files from main(postgres) .

Step15: To list out the backus follow below command

```
[barman@localhost ~]$ barman list-backup main
main 20160226T134400 - Fri Feb 26 13:44:07 2016 - Size: 504.0 MiB - WAL Size: 0 B
main 20160226T134115 - Fri Feb 26 13:41:29 2016 - Size: 496.8 MiB - WAL Size: 32.0 MiB

There are two backups listed 20160226T134400 is incremental backup and 20160226T134115 is full backup.
```

Step16: Now lets recover from backup

```
[barman@localhost ~]$ barman recover main 20160226T134400 /tmp/data
Starting local restore for server main using backup 20160226T134400
Destination directory: /tmp/data
Copying the base backup.
Copying required WAL segments.
Generating archive status files
Identify dangerous settings in destination directory.
IMPORTANT
These settings have been modified to prevent data losses
postgresql.conf line 209: archive_command = false
Your PostgreSQL server has been successfully prepared for recovery!
```

Backup is restored at location /tmp/data and while recovering user have to give latest backup ID

```
barman recover main latest /tmp/data
```

Step17: Now change owner of /tmp/data as 'postgres' and start the recovered instance.

```
[root@localhost tmp]# chown -R postgres:postgres data
[root@localhost data]# ls -lrth
total 156K
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 08:11 pg_twophase
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 08:11 pg_tblspc
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 08:11 pg_snapshots
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 08:11 pg_serial
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 08:11 pg_replslot
drwx------. 4 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 08:11 pg_multixact
drwx------. 4 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 08:11 pg_logical
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 08:11 pg_dynshmem
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 08:11 pg_commit_ts
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 4 Feb 26 08:11 PG_VERSION
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 88 Feb 26 08:11 postgresql.auto.conf.origin
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 08:11 pg_subtrans
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 1.6K Feb 26 08:11 pg_ident.conf
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 08:11 pg_clog
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 4.4K Feb 26 08:27 pg_hba.conf
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 22K Feb 26 13:40 postgresql.conf.origin
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 13:40 pg_stat
drwx------. 7 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 13:42 base
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 224 Feb 26 13:44 backup_label.old
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 22K Feb 26 13:45 postgresql.conf
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 88 Feb 26 13:45 postgresql.auto.conf
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 58 Feb 26 13:46 postmaster.pid
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 13:46 pg_notify
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 40 Feb 26 13:46 postmaster.opts
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 13:46 pg_log
drwx------. 3 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 13:46 pg_xlog
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 13:46 global
drwx------. 2 postgres postgres 4.0K Feb 26 13:53 pg_stat_tmp
[root@localhost tmp]# su - postgres
[postgres@localhost ~]$ pg_ctl -D master/ stop
waiting for server to shut down.... done
server stopped
[postgres@localhost ~]$ pg_ctl -D /tmp/data/ start
server starting
[postgres@localhost ~]$ LOG: redirecting log output to logging collector process
HINT: Future log output will appear in directory "pg_log".
```

psql to new instance which is recovered using barman at location /tmp/data.

```
[postgres@localhost ~]$ psql
psql (9.5.1)
Type "help" for help.
postgres=# \dt
List of relations
Schema | Name | Type | Owner
--------+------------------+-------+----------
public | pgbench_accounts | table | postgres
public | pgbench_branches | table | postgres
public | pgbench_history | table | postgres
public | pgbench_tellers | table | postgres
public | test | table | postgres
public | test1 | table | postgres
public | test2 | table | postgres
public | test4 | table | postgres
public | test5 | table | postgres
public | test6 | table | postgres
(10 rows)
postgres=# \l+
List of databases
Name | Owner | Encoding | Collate | Ctype | Access privileges | Size | Tablespace |                Description
-----------+----------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------+---------+------------+--------------------------------------------
postgres | postgres | UTF8 | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | | 466 MB | pg_default | default administrative connection database
template0 | postgres | UTF8 | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres +| 7129 kB | pg_default | unmodifiable empty database
| | | | | postgres=CTc/postgres | | |
template1 | postgres | UTF8 | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres +| 7129 kB | pg_default | default template for new databases
| | | | | postgres=CTc/postgres | | |
test | postgres | UTF8 | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | | 7265 kB | pg_default |
(4 rows)
postgres=# \c test
You are now connected to database "test" as user "postgres".
test=# \dt
List of relations
Schema | Name | Type | Owner
--------+-------+-------+----------
public | test1 | table | postgres
public | test2 | table | postgres
(2 rows)
test=# select count(*) from test1;
count
-------
1000
(1 row)
test=# show data_directory ;
data_directory
----------------
/tmp/data
(1 row)
test=#
```